# How to get exact database match with Symfony and Docrtrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i have a strange problem. I dont get an exact match of my user.

when i make an api request with the following json body:

```
{
  "userId": "2ab"
}
```

i search if there is any user with this (int)id the expected result have to be null. But i get a user with id 2. Is there a way to get only results with the given alphanumeric id which can be a real userId or any temporär alphanumeric id? guests in this case get a random alphanumeric id while users have their real id.

Or do i have to solve this by another way?

Comment: try ` php -r 'var_dump((int) "2ab");'` you'll see it returns `2`. Maybe you should validate the request body and throw a 400 response if the request body is not valid.

Comment: i have read now: user.id is an int field so thatswhy the string is converted to int automatically ans as u said the result is `2`. for now i make guest id's in the scheme guest_${id}. This works now.